# DAX command: How to calculate percentage by groups within a column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to write a DAX command to calculate percentage by groups within a column?

The table below illustrate the "Percentage by Type" that I would like to create. I have tried to use "SUMMARIZECOLUMNS" and "GROUPBY", but then there is an error like: "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting a Calculated Column or a Measure?

Comment: @JosWoolley Thanks for the question. I would like to have a calculated column.

Comment: Odd, normally you'd do that with a measure:
DIVIDE( [Count],CALCULATE([Count],ALL('TableName'[Type]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **Calculated Column**:

```
=
VAR ThisType = Table[Type]
RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        Table[Count],
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Table[Count] ),
            FILTER (
                Table,
                Table[Type] = ThisType
            )
        )
    )
```